# Communicating with multiple clients using one TCP socket python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am using TCP sockets to communicate between my server and clients. The server code and socket code are as below:

server:

```
from socket import *

HOST = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'
PORT = 1999
serversocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind((HOST,PORT))
print 'bind success'
serversocket.listen(5)
print 'listening'
while True:
    (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
    print ("Got client request from",address)
    #clientsocket.send('True')
    data = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    print data
    clientsocket.send('True')
    clientsocket.close()
```

client:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the socket to the port on the server given by the caller
server_address = ('xx.xx.xx.xx', 1999)
print >>sys.stderr, 'connecting to %s port %s' % server_address
sock.connect(server_address)

try:

    message = 'This is the message.  It will be repeated.'
    print >>sys.stderr, 'sending' 
    for x in range (0,1):
      name=raw_input ('what is ur name')
      print type(name)
      sock.send(name)
      print sock.recv(1024)

finally:
    sock.close()
```

I am able to communicate with the server from client and able to send and receive data. But the problem I am facing is that I am not able to send and receive data continuously from the server. I have to restart my client code on my laptop to send and receive data again from the server. The way the above client code is working is that when I give a keyboard input, then the socket sends data to server and server responds back. But in the client code, in the for loop if I do two iterations, for the second iteration the data I enter from keyboard is not reaching server. I need to restart my client code to send data again. How do I fix this ?

Also, when once client is connected to the server, the other cannot connect to the server. Any ideas on how to do this ?

Comment: Don't close the socket? Re-connect the socket?

Comment: Does a command exist to reconnect socket ?

Comment: Have you tried `sock.connect(server_address)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to design and implement a protocol that specifies what each side is supposed to do and then implement that protocol. You're expecting it to work by magic.

For example:

```
data = clientsocket.recv(1024)
```

I suspect you are expecting this to receive a "message". But TCP has no notion of messages. If you need to send and receive messages, you need to define precisely what a "message" is for your protocol and write code to send and receive them.

It may be helpful to look at the specifications for other protocols that use TCP such as HTTP, FTP, or IRC. It really is worth the time to write out a specification of your protocol before you write any code. It will save a *lot* of pain.